# Handle Facebook token expiration with Android app and webservices

Tags: android, facebook, token, facebook-android-sdk

Big problem. I have an Android app which is working with webservices (PHP) on my server. The users grant access to Facebook in my app (using SDK 3.0), and an access token is stored on the device. When needed, the app send the token to my server, where PHP files interact with Facebook thanks to this token (to display friends for example).

My question: how to handle token expiration in my app? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In SDK 3.5.2 you can do this:

```
Session.getActiveSession().getExpirationDate()
```

and you have the Date of expiration of token.
In SDK 3.0 I dont know if is possible call the same method.